# Nexus 5 GApps crashing after installing wrong GApps

Tags: cyanogenmod

I tried installing gapps for my phone with cyanogenmod but I installed one for Kitkat and not lollipop.

Now my phone acts all weird and nothing can be done on it, especially when it keeps saying `Unfortunately Android Keyboard (AOSP) stopped working`.

My computer also stopped recognizing my phone so I'm in deep trouble.

Any tips on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You can go back in recovery by pressing and holding **Volume+Up** buttons.

Then in recovery wipe `cache, dalvic cache, system` and reinstall ROM and correct GApps.

Now if you have ROM and GApps inside the phone its fine. Else you may have to use [ADB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979) if your PC doesnt recognize the phone.

- Set up ADB using link above and download both ROM and GApps *in your pc*.
- Restart phone in recovery mode.
- Connect phone to PC. Open CMD and run these commands->

`adb push Path_to_ROM_File_and_Name.zip /sdcard/`

`adb push Path_to_GApps_and_FileName.zip /sdcard/`

- These commands will transfer both ROM and GApps to your phone which you can normally install after wiping `cache, dalvic cache, system` (as already told above).

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I run the command it says 'error: device not found' and the phone is in recovery mode

Comment: I did everything else and it seems fine, is there something I'm doing wrong when it recognizes for the phone? Maybe the command?

Comment: íf you are using twrp you can also try disabling/enabling the "Enable MTP" option. That worked for me once when my phone too wasn't being recognized. Otherwise not being recognized is related to drivers